# Как сделать поиск для To Do List на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Может кто-то объяснить концепцию выполнения поиска для ТуДуЛист. К примеру у меня есть компонента, которая отрисовывает саму задачу.

```
<ListTasks/>
```

В нее приходят разные **props** из *Redux*. И таких компонент рисуется на странице большое количество, в зависимости сколько задач создаст пользователь. И мне бы хотелось что бы еще был поиск, при вводе в который уже с 1 буквы, он показал только те таски, в которых есть такое значение. Вот только примеры которые я нашел в интернете либо очень старые, либо не подходят мне.

Вот начальный *state*:

```
const initialState = {
    tasks: []
};
```

Вот что в нем, когда срабатывает редюссер при создании таски:

```
tasks: [{
       id: shortid.generate(),
       task: action.task,
       status: false
       }, ...state.tasks]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там нету никакой концепции стандартная фильтрация данных по значению.Я думаю сама логика todo листа у вас не правильно написано.

Во первых компонент который рисует задачи должен быть один.Который на вход получает список задач и показывает их пользователю.`ListTasks`

```
const ListTasks = props => {
  return (
    <ul className="todos">
      {props.todos.map(el => (
        <li key={el.id}>{el.task}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Еще нужен компонент который будет выполнять поиск назовем его `Search` у которого есть один `input`

```
const Search = props => {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => props.search(value)}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search here..."
    />
  );
};
```

Основной компонент который будет показывать этих двух и будет выполнять фильтрацию `App` с функцией `search` вся логика этой функции написано в комментариях внутри функции.

```
const App = () => {
  const initialArr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      task: "take out the trash",
      status: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      task: "Dinner with wife",
      status: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      task: "Meeting with Boss",
      status: false
    }
  ];

  const [todos] = useState(initialArr);
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    _ => {
      setFiltered(todos);
    },
    [todos]
  );

  const search = val => {
    //текущие задачи и новые отфильтрованные задачи
    let currentTodos = [], newList = [];
    if (val !== "") {
      //делаем копию нашего стейта
      currentTodos = todos;
      //фильтруем стейт в поисках совпадений
      newList = currentTodos.filter(todo => {
        // значение которое пользователь ввел и которое у нас
        // в стейте делаем строчными буквами чтобы конфликтов не было
        // мало ли пользователь ввель строчными буквами а у нас заглавные
        const lc = todo.task.toLowerCase();
        const filter = val.toLowerCase();
        // проверяем есть ли у нас этот элемент если есть возвращаем его
        return lc.includes(filter);
      });
    } else {
      // если в input ничего нету то есть пользователь стер то
      // что ввел тогда возвращаем все задачи
      newList = todos;
    }
    setFiltered(newList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Search {...{ search }} />
      <ListTasks todos={filtered} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Ссылка на [**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-mountain-onr23?file=/src/App.js:144-1600)