# Как правильно сделать поиск в ToDo приложении на React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вот мое приожение https://codesandbox.io/s/react-simple-code-editor-ecjyt?file=/src/App.js

**Как я реализовал поиск (Правильно ли?):**

1. У главного компонента в стейте есть свойство, searchActivated: false
2. Если в поиск введен хоть один символ то searchActivated: true, и основной компонент принимает другой отсортированный массив
3. Основной компонент на вход принимает список задач, либо если searchActivated: true - другой массив, который является измененной копией списка задач
4. Когда в поисковом импуте нет никаких символов, от он изменяет searchActivated на false и тогда показывается снова основной список задач

**Проблема:**
В момент когда в поиске введена хоть одна буква, и отсеивается определенный список, если я нажимаю удалить элемент, то удаляется он из основного списка задач, а не в отсортированнной копии. Даже если в обработчике onDelete поставить условие, что если searchActivated: true, то удалять из отсортированной копии, он всё равно не будет правильно работать.

Поиск должен работать по каждой введенной букве и дате из датапикера (пока не сделал ещё), при этом должен совместно работать с сортировкой (а это я вообще пока не понимаю как сделать)

Подскажите, что исправить?

Comment: Вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115512/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-to-do-list-%d0%bd%d0%b0-react/1115616#1115616

Comment: еще вместо `let` можно писать `const` (у меня их ~98%); сразу видно, в одном ли месте значение определяется

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал функциональные компоненты.
Стейт (`useState`) по минимуму: список дел, значения фильтров.
Сортировать/фильтровать можно и на рендере, а если нужна оптимизация -- `useMemo`.

Чем больше изменяемых состояний, тем легче запутаться.
Все производные значения (которые можно расчитать) лучше описать, как функции,
и если критично аккуратно настроить их кеширование/инвалидацию.